# How to create register Spring Security Authentication and Authorization with database

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm new spring developer .I want to create register Spring Security Authentication and Authorization with database. I download source code from github vai link below:

```
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-login-and-registration
```

I import source code to eclipse and run project after that i access url like below:

```
http://localhost:8877/spring-security-login-and-registration/user/registration
```

it show error 404 - Not Found. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `security:form-login login-page` tag in your spring security configuration xml file. It will automatically redirect your application to login page.

**REMEBER:** *to configure these url's in your Controller.*

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginFail"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <security:access-denied-handler
            error-page="/accessDenied" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/home" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFail" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>
```

This one is the best [reference tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892822/Spring-security-in-java) on spring security, I have came across. Please try to configure your application according to this and If you want both configurations(*JAVA/XML*) [REFER THIS](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/) or [MKYONG](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/).

I hope this will help.

Comment: i copy it pass into webSecurityConfig.xml. It have error like this: The prefix "security" for element "security:http" is not bound.

Comment: Just go through reference tutorial.